# CTRL shortcut persist error

Tags: javascript, hotkeys, shortcut, ctrl

I have been coding a couple of shortcuts for my web application, one of them saves the page i am working on, the other closes the page.

Both of these shortcuts work as do the functions themselves.

Both of these shortcuts are for webAdmins so that they can save and close our theme editing pages quickly. COMMAND+S saves the page and closes, whereas ESC just closes the page.

The issue is that when I press COMMAND+F to search for something it searches no problem, but if i press the "S" key afterwards or anytime during my search it acts as though i press COMMAND+S and saves and closes the page, as though it hit the shortcut, even though COMMAND+S are not being pressed at the same time.

Does anyone know how to explain this behavior? I have tried everything.

Here is my code:

```
enableHotkeys: function() {
    var isCommand = false;
    document.onkeyup=function(e) {
        if (e.which == 91) {
            isCommand=false;
        }
    };
    document.onkeydown=function(e) {
        if (e.which == 91) {
            isCommand = true;
        } else if (e.which == 83 && isCommand == true) {
            themeArchive.codeEditSave();
            return false;
        } else if (e.which == 27) {
            themeEditPanel.close();
            return false;
        }
    };
},
disableHotkeys: function() {
    document.onkeyup=function(e) {};
    document.onkeydown=function(e) {};
},
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? Since the handler invoked is `themeArchive.codeEditSave()` you should put some `console.log` after that line and before the `return false`, so you could understand the behaviour of your code. Try to debug `isCommand` and report the result

Comment: Check this out, it seems pretty good http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Comment: it seems that once it hits the first if after i press COMMAND+F it sets command equal to true yet never sets it to false afterwards if i haven't pressed anything. This makes it so that when i press S on onkeydown function it thinks i am pressing COMMAND+S. it seems as though my onkeyup is never being hit due to the command+f for some reason. I tried hitting command after command+f and saw it then recognized onkeyup and switched isCommand to false. Why would COMMAND+F be stopping onkeyup from being called?

Comment: i am unfortunately not allowed to add any external API or packages/scripts of any kind to our system. I must hard code it all. Thank you for the suggestion however.